# Text area content changes to "value" after displaying the content for a second

Tags: javascript, html

I have a query regarding the textarea field , I came across a very weird problem and I am trying to figure it out.
Firstly , here is what I am trying to do :

1. I have a drop down menu from which I select one of the template .
2. when selected I display the value of the template in the textarea  { this is the problematic part }
3. after that  I process the data  from the text area ..and well rest is not in picture.

Problem Description :
when i try to display the value selected from the Drop down menu to the text area using the function : `document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML=myvalue.value;`
it displays for a second and then the page reloads and shows the default value again .

here is my code:

javascript :

```
      <SCRIPT language="javascript">
function add(index_array) {

//create the form
    var myform = document.createElement("form");
    myform.id="k_form"
    for ( i =0 ; i <index_array.length ; i ++)
    {
        var mytext = document.createElement("input");
        mytext.tpye="text";
        mytext.name=index_array[i];
        mytext.value=index_array[i];
        mytext.id=index_array[i];
        myform.appendChild(mytext); 

    }

mydiv=document.getElementById("d_div");
mydiv.appendChild(myform);

       }
    </SCRIPT>
   <SCRIPT>
             function getkeywords() {
    //          var current_Date = new date();
    //          document.write(current_Date);

                var index_array = new Array();
                var myString = "one and a two and a three = $ and four = $ and five = $";
                var splitresult = myString.split(" ");

                    for(i = 0; i < splitresult.length; i++)
                    {
                    if (splitresult[i] == "$" && i > 1 )   //retireving the keywords..
                    {

                    index_array.push(splitresult[i-2]);
                    }
                    }
                    add(index_array);
                    /*                      
                    console.log("inside the if statement");
                    index_array.push(splitresult[i-2]); //saving the keywords for creating a new form with these as inputs....
                    }}
                    for ( i = 0 ; i < index_array.length ; i++ )
                          { 
                            add(index_array[i]);
                          }

                    */                      
                    }
               </SCRIPT>    
                <script>
             function populate_text()
             {
             var myvalue = document.getElementById("rawquery");
             document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML=myvalue.value;
             }
               </script>
```

the function "populate_text is the one that populates the textarea .
My HTML code is below :

```
               </HEAD>
              <BODY>
              <FORM>
                <BR/>
            <div align = "center">
            <form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
             Select a Template<br />
                <select name = "element" id = "rawquery">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option value = "Alpha query">Alpha</option>
                    <option value = "Betaquery">Beta</option>
                    <option value = "Gamma query">Gamma</option>
                    <option value = "Epsilon query">Epsilon</option>
                </select>
               <br /> 
             <input type = "submit"  onclick="populate_text()" name = "submit"><br /><br />
              </form>
              <textarea id = "mytext" name = "raw" rows = "10" cols = "50">raw      template</textarea>
               <br /><br />
        <INPUT type="button" value="Click To Enter Values"    onclick="getkeywords()"/>
             </div>
             <div align="center" id="d_div">
             <br/> <br/>
               </div>

               </FORM>
               </BODY>
               </HTML>
```

I believe the problem is with the page is rendered into the browser  that is line by line , but I cant figure out exactly what is causing this and how to fix it.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your form is submitting, add `return false;` at the end of your onclick function.

Comment: Tried `document.getElementById("mytext").value=myvalue.value;`?

Comment: @Musa , i have edited the protion . i am no loner generating the submit button i tried doing that to , i submit the value using "submit query" button which calls "populate_text" see the HTML code

Comment: When you click the submit button, it calls `populate_text`, then submits the form. That causes the page to get reloaded.  You should probably use `<input type="button" ...>` (instead of `type="submit"`).

Comment: @Musa , it displays as "submit query in firefox and submit in others this field :    <input type = "submit"  onclick="populate_text()" name = "submit"><br /><br /> i submit using this

Comment: @musa , yes that worked . thanks a lot ..can you give me link i want to know whats the difference between these two "submit" and "button" what exactly happens when you choose either one

Comment: @user1841314 when you use "submit" it submits your form automatically to the page you mentioned in action. A button doesn't submits unless you tell it to submit.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a submit button, and giving it an onclick handler. When the button is clicked, it executes your `onclick` handler, then proceeds to submit the form. This is why you see the value updating and then the page reloading.

If you don't want to submit the form with that button, then an `<input type="submit">` is the wrong choice. Use a button instead:

```
<input type="button" onclick="populate_text()" />
```

An `type=button` will do nothing by default, unlike a `type=submit` which submits the form by default.

---

[W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.submit.html) for `type=submit`:

> The input element with a type attribute whose value is "submit" represents a button for submitting a form.

[W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.button.html) for `type=button`:

> The input element with a type attribute whose value is "button" represents a button with no additional semantics.

Answer (score 0):

That's just because of you are defined input type as "submit"

```
<input type = "submit"  onclick="populate_text()" name = "submit" />
```

Whenever the action performed on submit, the page will reload. So, the default values will render again. You must to change it's type as "button".

The better use of `<select>` in html is, you can listen for its selected item changes like below,

```
<select name="element" id="rawquery" onchange="populate_text()">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value = "Alpha query">Alpha</option>
    <option value = "Betaquery">Beta</option>
    <option value = "Gamma query">Gamma</option>
    <option value = "Epsilon query">Epsilon</option>
</select>
```

and you can use your populate_text function to update the text area

```
function populate_text() {
    var myvalue = document.getElementById("rawquery");
    document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = myvalue.value;
}
```